# When I run this code in Heidi SQL it gives me an error "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" what's wrong?

Tags: mysql, heidisql

```
CREATE TABLE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `answer` (
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `options` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bit` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ans_group` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `fk2` (`a_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`a_no`) REFERENCES `questions` (`q_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `questions` (
  `q_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ques` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`q_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a table in the first statement that is only created in the second statement.

Try them in the opposite order.